# How to view just the public API "header" of a Swift file?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am now programming in Swift to edit the file/class `Chicken.swift` and I need to refer to the public api for `Food.swift`. Because the Chicken wants to eat Food.

So I click on `Food.swift` so I can RTFM. But instead of just getting the public api part that I am interested in, I get all the private crap and implementation details.

This is inefficient. Back in C/Objective-C/C++, I would just click on the `.h` file to get only the details I need.

Where does such information now exist for Swift development in XCode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: example]

How about using `counterparts` option

Comment: Perfect, awesome, thanks! It is very helpful to view the public interface because this helps validate that I am designing the correct API.

Answer (score 5):

Shortcut for this is

`CMD` + `CTRL` + `arrow up`